# How to get url id in php

Tags: php, syntax

I want to add an link button in page. The link get from the url eg:http://www.domain.com/links.php?id=9AO8VkSIODU. We need to get "9AO8VkSIODU" from the url using php. we try this string

```
<?php
$values = explode(",", $_GET["id"]);
?>
```

But it shows an syntax error

Comment: what's wrong with `$id = $_GET['id'];`?

Comment: show the complete code , its not clear yet

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/links.php?id=9AO8VkSIODU';
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $parts);
echo $parts['id'];

#=> 9AO8VkSIODU
```

[`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) will get a specific URL component
[`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) will parse a query string into a hash

If you are simply working within `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, you can use `$_GET['id']` directly.  The solution above works for an explicitly declared URL.

Comment: I wasn't making the bold assumption URL the OP is working with is the same as the server request URI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just

```
<?php $getvariable = $_GET['id']; ?>
```

Then use the $getvariable in your page

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$values = $_GET['id'];
echo $values;
?>
```

or

```
<?php
echo $_GET['id'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways

1. You can use parse_url() function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

1. By $_GET Server variable.

It return a array of all query string used in URL.

```
<?php
echo $_GET['id'];
?>
```